# How to open and save XML UTF8 unix file in VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, dom

I'm trying to do some changes in xml file which was created on unix system in Excel VBA.

I'm using this code:

```
Sub TestXML2()
    Dim XDoc As Object    
    Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    XDoc.Load ("C:\test\input.xml")
    XDoc.Save ("C:\test\output.xml")
    Set XDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

When i run this code, the code stops with error:
x80004005 Character cannot be saved in ASCII coding (translated from other language).
Part of the output file was saved but when i compare input and output files there are 2 differences:

1. New file has "crlf" end of lines, input has "lf" only.
2. In new file are  non ASCII chars converted to ASCII chars, ie: '&#252'; is converted to u (should be ü).

Comment: Ok, some progress. If I changed  MSXML2.DOMDocument to MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0. export is finished without error and non ASCII characters are ok in the new file. Only things i need to solve - end of lines are still <crlf> and spaces before xml tags are replaced with tabs. So i believe xml is valid now but i would like to have exact copy. Is it possible to define object how to care abut end of lines and spaces before tags?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. End of lines are still tranformed from `LF` to `CRLF` but i can live with it.

```
Sub TestXML2()
    Dim XDoc As Object    
    Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    XDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = True
    XDoc.Load ("C:\test\input.xml")
    XDoc.Save ("C:\test\output.xml")
    Set XDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```